# Replace character in file name ionic5 angular IOS

Tags: angular, ionic5

I use this code in ionic5 angular IOS to replace é with %CC%81 but it's not work

```
 const regex = /é/gi;
 fileName = fileName.replace(regex,"%CC%81");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `RegExp` as in:

`const regex = new RegExp(/é/gi);`

EDIT: After closer examination, I noticed that the letters you're trying to replace are *not* the same in your `la péériodeé` string, even if they look the same to you. So you'll need to add both types of 'e' in your regex, like:

`const regex = new RegExp(/é|é/gi);`

If this does not compile as you expect, it might be due to letters losing their characteristics, so to be safe - you can just copy your first 'e' (la p**é**ériodeé) and paste it at the first position in regex, then copy and paste the second 'e' (la pé**é**riodeé).

Comment: It's not work, nothing change. I try also new RegExp(/é/g); new RegExp(/\é/gi); new RegExp(/\é/g);  const regex = new RegExp(/\u00e9/gi);  const regex = new RegExp(/\u00e9/g);   regex = /é/gi;   regex = /\u00e9/gi;   regex = /é/g;   regex = /\u00e9/g;   /\é/gi;  /\é/g;

Comment: It seems that it does work https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-2b3u7b Are you sure you're not manipulating your fileName string somewhere else too?

Comment: It's not work in my ionic project. I use also     'fileName = fileName.replace(/\u00A0/g,"%C2%A0"); // non-break-spaces' and ' fileName = fileName.replace(/\s/g, "+"); // spaces'   and it's work I try also 'fileName = fileName.replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '%CC%81');' and it's work but for all special character. I want only for "é"

Comment: I found a origin of the problem, I use replace for name of file. When I copy/paste name of my file in your code, I reproduce the same bug. This is my entry : la péériodeé. You will have bug with first é.

Comment: When I save file with this name la période, é is unreplacable

Comment: please see my edited answer.

Comment: I found to type of é. They are é with one caracter and é ,when I save name of file, with two caracter e and accent. So I use it both to replace é