# Replace function not recognise é in fileName ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic5

I use `const regex = /é/gi; fileName = fileName.replace(regex,"%CC%81");` or `fileName = fileName.split("é").join("%CC%81");` and it is work with string and not with fileName.

You can test with this : fileName "période" and normal string "période" in https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-2b3u7b

Comment: Your code is working correctly, what's the problem?

Comment: Please see my edited answer to your initial question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409493/replace-character-in-file-name-ionic5-angular-ios/

Comment: I found to type of é. They are é with one caracter and é ,when I save name of file, with two caracter e and accent. So I use it both to replace é